# Can I set cells to remember a certain input method in Excel? If so, how?

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, input-languages

I have an Excel document with two columns. In one column, I write using the Japanese input method. In the next one I write using the standard one (Latin based).

So, can I set Excel to automatically switch input method when I move from one column to another? If so, how would I do it?

I'm using Excel 2011 for OS X.

Comment: I know this won't answer your question, but see the comments on my answer for a starting point (VBscript): http://superuser.com/q/436991/76571

Comment: @Excellll Thanks, I'll have a look at it although I'm not really an expert in scripts... :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it can. Not easily, anyway. Because input method is managed by the OS, right? I don't think an app could have any control on it even if it wanted to

If you don't mind it, there's always the shortcut LeftAlt-RightShift, in Windows, that switches input methods quickly. There's probably something similar in Mac OS.

The only other way I see would be to set up a macro that would bind your Tab key to change input methods as well. You'd have to disable it once you're done working. Not too practical.

Oh yeah, and if it's okay for your whole column to be in hiragana only, you can write text in the Japanese column in romaji, and once you're done, select it all and run a Find and replace for every syllable. I know, it's a lot of characters. But well.

If you were good in programming, you could set up a tool that would automatically run that replacement in Excel. There are various tools on the Web that do it for text you input. There should be a way to port it to Excel, but... I don't know it.

There might even be some tools that can intelligently-ish put kanji in. But again, they'd need to be ported to Excel.

Sorry I can't be of more help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done.

I use the Input Rules on the Data tab.
(I have to set the "Options", "Language", "Editing Language" to "Japanese")

Just go to the "Data" tab and then select "Conditional Rules" from the "Data Tools" group. There will now be a new tab on the right called "Japanese Input". Set one column to "On", the other to "Off", and you're ready to go.

Chris