# in microsoft excel how to define a default language for columns

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, automation, formatting, language

Hi I'm working on a dictionary and need to have English words in one column and Persian translation in another. but it takes time changing language every time I want to type the English and Persian words. I was wondering is there a trick to change language between columns automatically? for example, column A default language is set to English and column B to Persian.

Many thanks in advance...

Comment: Use the selectionchanged event of the worksheet to change the keyboard input language, as advised here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36340180/how-do-i-change-the-input-language-programmatically-with-vba

Comment: The default language doesn't seem to change, as a workaround, you can use vba to do similar features:  https://superuser.com/questions/436991/setting-the-content-language-of-cells-in-excel

Comment: Instead of typing in both English and Persian, type in one and let Excel do the translation for you  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41671778/how-can-i-use-google-translate-api-to-translate-text-in-microsoft-excel]