# Is it possible to assign Arabic language to one column in excel and make all other columns in English?

Tags: microsoft-excel

As you can see below I am making a GPS Tracking report here

The first column shows where the car stopped at which needs to be in Arabic while the stop duration should be in English.

It's difficult to just switching from one language to another so I would like the first column to be automatically in Arabic and second one in English.

Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: Unsure of what you mean by this. The stop duration seems to be in a time format, but is that time format Arabic? Or something else? What does the `8H` mean? 8 hours? And then after that it is a hyphenated list of minutes? Like `5M-54M-` means “5 Minutes, 54 Minutes…” and such? Or is that some GPS format?

Comment: the - seperates the times so the first stop for that car was for 8 hours and 5 minutes and then the next time it stopped was for 54 minutes, on first column i write the location where it stopped and on second i write the duration, i just want to make the duration column automaticlly in english without having to press alt + shift everytime i switch

Comment: Do you want a different keyboard layout for the columns, or does English require CAPSLOCK to be set?

Comment: @AkrmZaki All makes sense. But you mean you want the column name to be in English? I mean dates and times are clear; but the column name is clearly in Arabic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the keyboard input / language bar is controlled at system level (e.g. by Windows), I don't think you can set it per cell like you want.

Perhaps if you are willing to add VBA code to your spreadsheet and save it as a macro enabled .xlsm file, you can trigger the language bar toggle via a dll call within the selection change event. See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/436991/setting-the-content-language-of-cells-in-excel) for a similar question. Though I'm guessing this isn't worth the effort.

As an alternate solution, you can enter your location and times using the arabic keyboard only, then use a formula to replace arabic/delimiter characters with H and M. E.g. enter `8:5;-54;-54;` then in the next column type a formula `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B2, ":", "H"), ";", "M")`.